# array_filter skip null or 0 value

Tags: php

I want split an url like this: `$url = "log/getLog/0/categorias/5/";` using this function:

```
$urlParts = array_filter(explode('/', $url));
```

but this return:

> array(4) { [0]=> string(11) "log" [1]=> string(8) "getLog" [3]=> string(10) "categorias" [4]=> string(1) "5" }

how you can see the `0` value it was skipped. What I can do for avoid this bug?

Comment: Pass an anonymous function where you just filter out `""`

Comment: uhm an example please? @Rizier123

Comment: Look at the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php  There you also have a link what it filters out by default when you don't pass a callback

Comment: The length of the string log is not 11!

Comment: You could `$url =  rtrim($url, '/');` first, and not bother with the array_filter.

Comment: @Progrock but I need to split each part of the url..

Comment: You've already done that with the explode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`array_filter` will remove all elements having `null`, `empty` and `0` values.
To handle value `0` in your case, callback function can be used where you can explicitly specify which values to allow and which to ignore.

I have created a custom callback function that will accept `0` but filter `null`, `empty` and `false` values.

```
<?php
$url = "log/getLog/0/categorias/5/";

$urlParts = array_filter(explode('/', $url), function($v){
    return $v !== false && !is_null($v) && ($v != '' || $v == '0');
});

print_r($urlParts);

$url = array(
         0 => 'foo',
         1 => false,
         2 => -1,
         3 => null,
         4 => '',
         5 => 0
      );

$urlParts = array_filter($url, function($v){
    return $v !== false && !is_null($v) && ($v != '' || $v == '0');
});

print_r($urlParts);
?>
```

> Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => log
    [1] => getLog
    [2] => 0
    [3] => categorias
    [4] => 5
)
Array
(
    [0] => foo
    [2] => -1
    [5] => 0
)
```

Working [Demo](https://eval.in/522441)

Comment: You'd think that `empty($v) && '0' != $v` would be shorter to achieve the same result

Comment: It is shorter but wont work in case of 'blank' and '0'. Would be helpful if you can create a working fiddle :).

Comment: everything is looking good, except maybe a bit messy
: 
`return $v !== false && !is_null($v) && ($v != '' || $v == '0');`

which probably might be replaced with a bit cleaner
: 

`return !in_array($v, [false, null, ''], true);`